# How to convert ResultSet into a useful integer?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, resultset

I am trying to perform an SQL query to see how many records there are in my table.
The SQL that I'm using for this is `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable;`
The query is then being executed and stored in a `ResultSet`.

```
int recordNumber = 0;
    String sqlString = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable;";
    try {
        ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery(sqlString);
        resultSet.next();
        recordNumber = Integer.parseInt(rst);
    } catch (Exception e) {}
```

My questions is how do I get the number of records out of the `ResultSet`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `ResultSet` has a series of `getXYZ(int)` methods to retrieve columns from it by their relative index and corresponding `getXYZ(String)` methods to retrieve those columns by their alias. In your case, using the index variant  [`getInt(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getInt-int-) would be the easiest:

```
recordNumber = resultSet.getInt(1);
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to use this query adding a name `count` to column like this :

```
  String sqlString = "SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM myTable";
```

And then with `getInt(..)` you can retrieve the value like this:

```
    if(resultSet.next())
     recordNumber = resultSet.getInt(count);// with name of column
```

Or using the index of column like this:

```
    if(resultSet.next())
     recordNumber = resultSet.getInt(1);
```

Comment: why you call Integer.parseInt where ResultSet#getInt already returns int?